# b2body which didn't simulate physics

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

guys, I'm newbie in box2d. Can you help me?
I want to make b2body, which will move only vertical. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make it kinetic, then you can manipulate it as you wish.

Comment: My app is crashing, when i'm trying to move kinematic body

Comment: b2MouseJointDef md;
    md.bodyA = _groundBody;
    md.bodyB = firstBase;
    md.target = locationWorld;
    md.collideConnected = true;
    md.maxForce = 1000.0f * firstBase->GetMass();
    //crash after next row
    _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)world->CreateJoint(&md);

Comment: Are you trying to move a kinematic body with a mouse joint? You can only move them by setting their location directly with SetTransform or by using SetLinearVelocity/SetAngularVelocity.